# Remove element from array if string contains any of the characters

Tags: php, arrays

Remove element from array if string contains any of the characters.For example Below is the actual array.

```
array(1390) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "Rs.52.68""
  [1]=>
  string(20) ""php code generator""
  [2]=>
  string(9) ""Rs.1.29""
  [3]=>
  string(21) ""php codes for login""
  [4]=>
  string(10) ""Rs.70.23""

 }
```

I need the array to remove all the elements which start with `RS.`

Expected Result

```
 array(1390) {
      [0]=>
      string(20) ""php code generator""
      [1]=>
      string(21) ""php codes for login""


     }
```

What i tried so far :

```
foreach($arr as $ll)
{

if (strpos($ll,'RS.') !== false) {
    echo 'unwanted element';
}
```

From above code how can i remove unwanted elements from array .

Comment: `$arr = array_filter($arr, function($value) { return strpos($value, 'Rs.') !== false; }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the `$key` in the `foreach` loop and use `unset()` on your array:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $ll) {
    if (strpos($ll,'RS.') !== false) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
```

Note that this would remove none of your items as "RS" never appears. Only "Rs".

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a job for [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). It allows you to specify a callback function that can do any test you like. If the callback returns true, the value if returned in the resulting array. If it returns false, then the value is filtered out.

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, 
  function($item) { 
    return strpos($item, 'Rs.') === false; 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Rs is different than RS you want to use `stripos` rather than `strpos` for non case sensitive checking

```
foreach($arr as $key => $ll)
{    
  if (stripos($ll,'RS.') !== false) {
    unset($arr[$key]);
  }
}
```

or use `arrayfilter` as pointed out